# A novice substitution in differentiation, why is it wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Edit: It is given that $f$ is continuously differentiable.

One of my colleague's student wrote this:

> Let $x=2-h,$
> $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(2+3h)-f(2-h)}{h}=4\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+4h)-f(x)}{4h}=4f'(2)$$

We feel repelled to accept the latter equality, but aren't sure why, other than that we've always used the more common method of making up extra terms $-f(2)+f(2)$ in the nominator. I've tried to find an example where the student's treatment of two related variables in a single limit would lead to an error, but nothing can seem to go wrong. What would you say as a teacher of calculus?

Comment: I feel like this should be correct as if we treat x as a separate variable which tends to 2, this becomes valid as we can take the limit (x goes to 2) of the limit mentioned here.

Comment: However, my logic isn't rigorous either. Trying to prove this using the epsilon-delta definition might be fruitful.

Comment: What is $x$? The parameter in $f(2-h)$ is not fixed, if you want to get up to shenanigans like this you need some additional continuity properties of the derivative. As stated, neither of the left two limits equal the right without smoothness properties or explaining what $x$ is.

Comment: @copper.hat I omitted the obvious substitution of $x=2-h$ which the student had stated. Can you elaborate on the continuity/smoothness properties?

Comment: I’m perhaps I’m being dumb, but why are we getting an extra factor of four in the denominator?

Comment: Also can I ask what the full problem statement is?

Comment: @Chris If you're viewing this on a phone, that 4 in the first line of equations is supposed to be multiplied to the second limit.

Comment: @HyobinLee gotcha

Comment: @Chris "Say f(x) is an antiderivative of a continuous function g(x). Find the limit (left hand)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break his work into steps, first, he **hides** $(2-h)$ by $x$, and gets

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+4h)-f(x)}{4h}=f'(x)$$

Next, he plugs in $x=2-h$, and gets
$$f'(x)=f'(2-h)$$ Surely he has used this action $\lim_{h\to0}$ when deriving $f'(x)$, to reach the answer $f'(x)=f'(2)$, he has to take an extra  $\lim_{h\to0}$ operation and argues:

$$f'(2)=\lim_{h\to0} f'(2-h)\tag{1}$$

Surely this is the incorrect way, since it is ambiguous to let $h$ approach to $0$ twice. Further, his argument eq.(1) implies: **the function is differentiable at** $x=2$, **and its derivative is continuous at** $x=2$.

To attack this logic flaw, we can find a counter-example, such that the derivative function is **NOT continous**, then we are done. A famous example is:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0. 
\end{cases}
$$

where $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and its derivative is
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} 
  2 x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0,
\end{cases}
$$

which is not continuous at $x=0$. To apply this counter-example to your case, we just shift $x$ to $x-2$, so take the $f$ as

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  (x-2)^2 \sin(1/(x-2)) &\mbox{if } x \neq 2 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=2. 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: We have agreed that the implicitly assumed continuity of f' is what was bugging us, and even though the original context has that f' is continuous, this seems worthwhile to point out. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are welcome.